# jquery check if following LI has class

Tags: jquery

In jQuery - how can I check to see if a `<li>` that follows another has a class or not.

Markup is:

```
<ul>
<li><a href"#">Title 1</a></li>
<li class="LI_sector_child"><a href"#">Title 2</a></li>
<li><a href"#">Title 3</a></li>
<li><a href"#">Title 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, I want to be able to target the 3rd li element as shown above (Title 3) so I can add a class to that.

So, I am looking to find 2 LI's that are next to each other in the DOM that don't have the class "LI_sector_child" applied.

Note - I cant use nth-child / nth-of-type as the UL is generated dynamically each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match an LI that doesn't have the class, has a following LI, and the following LI also doesn't have the class. So it selects the first of every pair that don't have the class.

```js
$("li:not(.LI_sector_child)").filter(function() {
  return $(this).next('li').length && !$(this).next().hasClass("LI_sector_child");
}).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href "#">Title 1</a></li>
  <li class="LI_sector_child"><a href "#">Title 2</a></li>
  <li><a href "#">Title 3</a></li>
  <li><a href "#">Title 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(".LI_sector_child").next("li:not('.LI_sector_child')")` Find out more about `:not()` selector, `.not()` method in the [jQuery docs](https://jquery.com/)

```js
$(".LI_sector_child").next("li:not('.LI_sector_child')").addClass("red");
```

```css
.red {background: red;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href "#">Title 1</a></li>
  <li class="LI_sector_child"><a href "#">Title 2</a></li>
  <li><a href "#">Title 3</a></li>
  <li><a href "#">Title 4</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alernatively using the sibling combinator `+`

```js
$(".LI_sector_child + li:not('.LI_sector_child')").addClass("red");
```

```css
.red {background: red;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href "#">Title 1</a></li>
  <li class="LI_sector_child"><a href "#">Title 2</a></li>
  <li><a href "#">Title 3</a></li>
  <li><a href "#">Title 4</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```